# How to add rows and insert data in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

Can someone help me ?

i want datagridview display data

```
datagridview1.datasource = _db.Students.Tolist();
```

and it display on data grid. and has a button.if the button click, datagridview1 will add the rows with no data. And the User fill the rows. when it done it will save to database.

How to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, DataGridView has a .Rows.Add property, like this:

```
dataGridView.Rows.Add
```

and

```
dataGridView.Rows.Insert
```

You should convert your data into an array first.
Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx

Comment: in this case i must to create an unbound datagridview ? its the answer. thanks simoneF

Comment: Try with both bound and unbound, I guess if the inner .Table points to null, the above method will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "createNewRecord")
    {
             //Another Gridview will be created here, and it will contains EditTemplate.
             //you can use that gridview to receive data by Edit.
    }
}
```

Sample of Edit tamplate gridview

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <EditItemTemplate><asp:textboxt id="txt1" runat="server" /></EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```